# How Can i Call Middleware in this prefix Route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

Hello I am new in laravel framework. can anyone tell me how to apply middleware in this following route?

```
Route::prefix('Admin')->group(function (){

    Route::get('/', 'UserlistController@index');

    Route::post('create', 'UserlistController@create')->name('create');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various to call middleware in the group function.

**1st way**:- Define middleware after group function.

```
Route::prefix('Admin')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/', 'UserlistController@index');
    Route::post('create', 'UserlistController@create')->name('create');
})->middleware('yourmiddlewarename');
```

**2nd way**:- to define middleware with a prefix.

```
Route::middleware(['yourmiddlewarename'])->prefix('Admin')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/', 'UserlistController@index');
    Route::post('create', 'UserlistController@create')->name('create');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>['auth']], function(){
    Route::post('favorite/{post}/add','FavoriteController@add')->name('post.favorite');
    Route::post('review/{id}/add','ReviewController@review')->name('review');
    Route::get('file-download/{id}', 'PostController@downloadproject')->name('project.download');
    Route::post('file-download/{id}', 'PostController@downloadproject');
});
```

Comment: This thing i know but i want to use middleware in my above code. is it possible??

Comment: Route::prefix('Admin')->group('middleware' => ['m1', 'm2'] ,function (){

    Route::get('/', 'UserlistController@index');

    Route::post('create', 'UserlistController@create')->name('create');

});

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Laravel's` `Route::group()` method for proper grouping of routes.

You can group routes like the following:

```
Route::group(['as' => 'for_named_route','prefix' =>'for_prefixing','namespace' => 'for_namespacing', 'middleware' => 'for_middleware'],function(){
  // Your route will go here
);
```

For your coding purpose your route group should be like the following:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'for_prefixing','middleware'=>'for_middleware'],function(){
  // Your route will go here
  Route::get('/', 'UserlistController@index');

  Route::post('create', 'UserlistController@create')->name('create');
);
```

You can also pass multiple middleware using an array like:

`'middleware'=>['middleware_1','middleware_2']`